# Is it possible to install Windows on a Mac mini?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, multi-boot, mac-mini

I brought a whole new Mac mini as I am an iPhone developer - I prefer to use it.

But most of my family members are not used to macOS and they don't know how to operate basic functions in macOS like:

- Managing files
- Opening documents
- Browser & many many other issues.

It's not their age to learn more, people like us ( computer geek ) can easily get into new systems. I had many attempted efforts to teach them for all these above topics in Windows.

So while I know how to use a Mac, they don't know.

In short, I just want to install Windows. So, that they can feel that Mac mini is for all members not for just me. Can I do this?

- Can I dual boot Windows and macOS on a Mac mini ?
- Does it void any of Apple’s warranties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly legal and also support by Apple. You can find information [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/50374/2006/04/winmacfaq.html) (from 2006, so some things might have changed) and [here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=mac/10.5/en/11889.html).

But it is easy to do. Just go to *Applications →  Utilities → Boot Camp Assistant* and follow the instructions.

*([Direct link to the install instructions](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Boot_Camp_Install-Setup_10.6.pdf))*

Make sure you make a backup before, just in case ;)

Comment: @Felix. "It is perfectly legal & support by Apple" - made me very happy.

Comment: @sagar: Have a look at this page http://www.apple.com/macosx/compatibility/ , they even promote it ;) So really it is no big deal.

Comment: @sugar: It's not that Microsoft don't allow their systems to run OS X but that Apple will only allow OS X to be run on Apple hardware.